# How to do a multi level if else query in excel?

Tags: database, excel, if-statement

I'm trying to do a multi level if else query in excel, where it would check multiple variables and if it falls into one of the categories then it would - a percentage and if it doesn't fall into any of the categories then it would say "N/A"

The pseudo code would look something like this:

```
If $income <90,000 and $age is <65 then - 27.82%,
else if $income range(90,000 - 105,000)  and $age <65 then $premium - 18.55%,
else if $income range(105,001 - 140,000)  and $age <65 then $premium - 9.27%,
else if $income >140,000 and $age <65 then - 0%,
else if $income <90,000 and $age range(65-69) then $premium - 32.46%,
else if $income range(90,000 - 105,000) and $age range(65-69) then $premium - 23.18%,
else if $income range(105,001 - 140,000)  and $age range(65-69) then $premium - 13.91%,
else if $income >140,000 and $age range(65-69) then $premium - 0%,
else if $income <90,000 and $age <70 then - 37.09%,
else if $income range(90,000 - 105,000)  and $age <70 then $premium - 27.82%,
else if $income range(105,001 - 140,000)  and $age <70 then $premium - 18.55%,
else if $income >140,000 and $age <70 then $premium - 0%,
else "NA";


$income = cell j4
$age = cell i4
$premium = cell q4
```

I'm able to do a single level query that looks something like this:

```
=IF(AND(I5>64,I5<69,J5>90000,J5<105001),800*$Y$5,"NA")
```

but I'm not sure how to do a multiple if else statements in excel to capture all the possible categories or if there is a better way.

Comment: you can nest the if function to achieve this, the syntax is like this =IF(Condition, TRUE, IF(Condition, TRUE, IF(....)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would group the various if statements into age ranges first, then do if statements for income within each age group.

Something like this:

```
=IF(I4<65,
    IF(J4<90000,27.82,IF(J4<=105000,18.55,IF(J4<=140000,9.27,0))),
    IF(I4<=69,
        IF(J4<90000,32.46,IF(J4<=105000,23.18,IF(J4<=140000,13.91,0))),
        IF(J4<90000,37.09,IF(J4<=105000,27.82,IF(J4<=140000,18.55,0)))))
```

Here is a version with comments (*don't actually paste this into Excel*):

```
=IF(I4<65, // if the age is less than 65
    IF(J4<90000,27.82,IF(J4<=105000,18.55,IF(J4<=140000,9.27,0))),
    // else if the age is less than or equal to 69
    IF(I4<=69,
        IF(J4<90000,32.46,IF(J4<=105000,23.18,IF(J4<=140000,13.91,0))),
        // else (the age must be 70 or greater so need to specify this)
        IF(J4<90000,37.09,IF(J4<=105000,27.82,IF(J4<=140000,18.55,0)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested IF Statements:

```
IF( condition1, value_if_true1, IF( condition2, value_if_true2, value_if_false2 ))
```

IF-ELSE Statements:

```
IF condition1 THEN
value_if_true1
ELSEIF condition2 THEN
value_if_true2
ELSE
value_if_false2
END IF
```

Comment: I tried doing a nested query. `=IF(AND(I4 < 65, J4 < 90000), 800*(1 - 0.27),"NA", =IF(AND(I4>64,I4<69,J4>90000,J4<105001),800*0.35,"NA", =IF(AND(I4<69,J4>105001,J4<140000),800*0.18,"NA")))` It doesn't seem to give me an answer.

Comment: You've got too many equal signs - should just be one at begin of formula. A nested `IF` is always the `FALSE` condition of the previous `IF`, taking the place of the "NAs" in your example.